# SharePoint content editor web part is missing the url to HTML file in edit mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-parts, content-query-web-part

This is a weird one, but I am not sure if I am missing something here. There used to be a location for the link to HTML files in content editor web parts. I cannot find the url now! I want to know which HTML file the web part is showing at the moment so I can modify it. It not under any of these: Appearance, Layout, Advanced.

[image]

Comment: Try to insert a new one to confirm whether the DOM hide by customization(custom CSS), attach the div tag id for your reference. ToolPartctl00_MSOTlPn_EditorZone_Edit0g_xxx

Answer (score 0):

The problem was SharePoint Online's content type editor had gone missing. So I managed to enable the feature back on again. As soon as I enabled the feature, the content editor edit panel went back to its previous status. I used this to do it:
[Content Editor Web Part missing on SharePoint Online](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_win10-msoversion_other/content-editor-web-part-missing-on-sharepoint/39a8e03e-35d4-4671-8e28-f8ab57bfffd0)